# How to set pagination in laravel without refreshing the whole page

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, pagination

**Controller**

```
    //Pagination
    $page = 1;
    $perPage = 5;
    $Reviews = DB::select($Reviews);
    $currentPage = Input::get('page', 1) - 1;
    $pagedData = array_slice($Reviews, $currentPage * $perPage, $perPage);
    $Reviews =  new Paginator($pagedData, count($Reviews), $perPage);
    $Reviews->setPath($id);

    $this->data['review_view'] = 'userreviews.reviews';
    $this->data['pages'] = 'hotelroom.detailed_page';

    return view($page, $this->data, compact('Reviews'));
```

I use custom pagination.

And in my view I use `userreviews.blade.php` which was inserted into the `detailed_page.blade.php` & it was considered as main view file.

**View**

```
//userreviews.blade.php

    @foreach($Reviews as $rev)
            //Displaying contents
    @endforeach
    <div class="pagination">
           <?php echo $Reviews->appends($_REQUEST)->render(); ?>
    </div>

//detailed_page.blade.php

    <div class="review_view">
           @include($review_view)
    </div>
```

These are my view files..

Here, the pagination works properly..

The problem is the when I click the pagination links it take me to the next page..

But,it refresh the whole page,and I lost my other results in that page.

Is there any other ways for pagination that only change the specified view file.Someone help me..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Use ajax for this;

Comment: How should I do it!!!....

Comment: Do you have any idea of ajax? [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and return records only and show where you want to;

Comment: I know how to do ajax.Here I pass the values to the controller using the Ajax get method only..I dont know how to use Ajax for this pagination

Comment: pass pageNumber too to get request and get this pageNumber in php and send data back for that page;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a container in which you want to display the results. Then create a Blade subtemplate that displays all the content for that container. Use something like jQuery to listen for click events and get the next/previous result. Something like this below (pseudo, untested)

In page.blade.php

```
<div id="results">@include('page_details')</div>
```

In page_details.blade.php

```
@foreach($items as $item)
  // your $item display..
@endforeach

// return $from from your controller. It represents the current $_GET['from']
<span class="prev" data-from="{{ $from- 1}}">Previous</span> 
<span class="next" data-from="{{ $from + 1 }}">Next</span>
```

In your javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(document).on('click', '.prev, .next', function() { 
    $.ajax({
      // the route you're requesting should return view('page_details') with the required variables for that view
      url: '/route/as/defined/in/routes-file?from=' + $(this).attr('data-from'),
      type: 'get'
    }).done(response) { 
      $('div#results').html(response);
    }
  });
});
```

**Tackling Error 500 when sending ajax requests**

Also make sure you don't run into token verification issues (9 out of 10 times the reason you get HTTP 500 errors) when sending data via ajax. Set up a meta tag in your master layout like: `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ crsf_token() }}">`

And add the following to your javascript as well; it sends the current token automatically with the headers with each ajax request you make.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

Comment: I usually put it right after `$(document).ready(function() { `

Comment: You said that should be in the jquery..Okay I try this... :)

Comment: No, I said it needs to be in your javascript file as well.

Comment: Yeah ok...I'll try

Comment: Did it work? If so, feel free to accept this answer as it rewards folks for taking time to help you with your question.

Comment: Sorry Ben it didn't works for me..I use normal Ajax pagination for my code.Might be works for others.So I mark it as an accepted one.